# Alignment of icon in the statusbar on Android

Tags: android, notifications

Is it possible to align an icon in Android's status bar to the right?
I would like to have an icon indicating that the application is running on the right side of status bar but I haven't found any solution for this.

Comment: It's in the status bar I would like to align an icon.

Comment: would you like to show activity progress indicator in activity's title bar?

Comment: no not activity progress, just an icon indicating that application running. Not really needed for my application, but it's a school assignment=). The problem is that I would like to align the icon to the right, is that possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the icon slots on the right are reserved for the system.